# Bing maps API: Is there a way to use truck routing for distance matrix?

Tags: c#, bing-maps, azure-maps

I want to get a set of distances between truck and pickup points. I saw that there is REST API for truck routing and that there is also API for distance matrix. Url for requests to both APIs is different. From microsoft documentation for distance matrix API i can see `travelMode` parameter but it can only be set to vehicle, walking or transit.

Is there a way to use truck routing for distance matrix?

**Request url template for track route:**

```
https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/Truck?wayPoint.1={wayPpoint1}&viaWaypoint.2={viaWaypoint2}&waypoint.3={waypoint3}&wayPoint.n={waypointN}&heading={heading}&optimize={optimize}&avoid={avoid}&distanceBeforeFirstTurn={distanceBeforeFirstTurn}&routeAttributes={routeAttributes}&dateTime={dateTime}&tolerances={tolerances}&distanceUnit={distanceUnit}&vehicleHeight={vehicleHeight}&vehicleWidth={vehicleWidth}&vehicleLength={vehicleLength}&vehicleWeight={vehicleWeight}&vehicleAxles={vehicleAxles}&vehicleTrailers={vehicleTrailers}&vehicleSemi={vehicleSemi}&vehicleMaxGradient={vehicleMaxGradient}&vehicleMinTurnRadius={vehicleMinTurnRadius}&vehicleAvoidCrossWind={vehicleAvoidCrossWind}&vehicleAvoidGroundingRisk={vehicleAvoidGroundingRisk}&vehicleHazardousMaterials={vehicleHazardousMaterials}&vehicleHazardousPermits={vehicleHazardousPermits}&key={BingMapsKey}
```

**Request url template for distance matrix:**

```
https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Routes/DistanceMatrix?origins={lat0,long0;lat1,lon1;latM,lonM}&destinations={lat0,lon0;lat1,lon1;latN,longN}&travelMode={travelMode}&startTime={startTime}&timeUnit={timeUnit}&key={BingMapsAPIKey}
```

Comment: Hi kkamil, Can you show us what code you have tried? Stack Overflow isn't for broad scoped "how do I" type questions. If you have code that isn't working, please post it and we can help you debug it.  Please take a moment to get familiar with the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Well, i didn't try anything special because urls are too different and i dont have any idea right now. I cant find anything on microsoft website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Bing Maps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/routes/calculate-a-distance-matrix), only the following travel modes are supported:

- driving (car)
- walking
- public transit

You may want to take a look at Azure Maps, it does support truck based distance matrices as [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/route/postroutematrix). Azure Maps supports calculating distance matrices for the following travel modes:

- bicycle
- bus
- car
- motorcycle
- pedestrian
- taxi
- truck
- van

Here is some additional resources on Azure Maps:

- Overview: https://azure.com/maps
- Documentation: https://aka.ms/AzureMapsDocs
- Getting Started: https://aka.ms/AzureMapsGettingStarted
- Code Samples: https://aka.ms/AzureMapsSamples
- Videos: https://aka.ms/AzureMapsVideos
- Blog: https://aka.ms/AzureMapsBlog
- Developer Forums: https://aka.ms/AzureMapsForums
- Case Studies: https://aka.ms/AzureMapsCaseStudies
- Pricing: https://aka.ms/AzureMapsPricing
- Azure Maps Feedback (UserVoice): https://aka.ms/AzureMapsFeedback

Answer (score 0):

I found a library [BingMapsRestToolkit](https://github.com/microsoft/BingMapsRESTToolkit) where you can in distance matrix set TravelMode to truck but it's basically just added functionality which actually sends many requests to truck routing API. For free user max queries number per second is just 5 so it's not really helpful because it's slow, maybe if you have enterprise license for Bing maps API then it can kinda help someone.

Example:

```
    var request = new DistanceMatrixRequest()
    {
        BingMapsKey = bingApiKey,
        Origins = new List<SimpleWaypoint>
        {
            new SimpleWaypoint(new Coordinate(vehiclePosition.Latitude, vehiclePosition.Longitude))
        },
        Destinations = destinationWaypoints,
        TravelMode = TravelModeType.Driving,
        VehicleSpec = new VehicleSpec
        {
            VehicleLength = 16.5,
            VehicleWeight = 20000
        }
    };

    var response = request.Execute().Result; // Or await request.Execute()
```

`Origins` and `Destinations` are `List<SimpleWaypoint>`

`TravelMode` set to truck

Comment: I wrote that library :)

Comment: Oh, it's helpful ^^

Comment: @rbrundritt by the way, where does originId or destinationId come from in distance matrix? Is it in the order the List<SimpleWaypoint> is in?

Comment: I haven't touched that library in a few years. I'm purely focused on Azure Maps these days.